# Facebook Paper like animation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, animation

I am building an application which has a Facebook paper app like animation but i am not able to understand how can i do it.

The only thing i can think about is custom view controller transition but don't know from where to start this particular animation because initially the subview (which can be moved and open based on interaction) is closed.

i have tried to show the Required animation in below images.

[image] [image]

Help Appreciated..

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: No buddy fortunately for me my client dropped the idea of including above animation.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook open sourced their framework that they used for such animations.

Have a look at [Async Display Kit](http://asyncdisplaykit.org)

Comment: That is fine but what if I want to create that small animation on my own?

Comment: Have a look at the way it's done in the project and see how they did it, then you can try and do it yourself.

Comment: above sample code isn't compiling it says "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." i have never worked with pod files...

Comment: That's a whole different problem.

Comment: @Anorak "Have a look at the way it's done in the project and see how they did it, then you can try and do it yourself" - Which project are you referring to? I ran all of the example projects except the "Placeholders" project and none of them display this animation. Is it in the "Placeholders" example, or were you referring to something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the [Facebook ***pop***](https://github.com/facebook/pop/blob/master/README.md) library.

It's `"an extensible animation engine for iOS and OS X. In addition to basic static animations, it supports spring and decay dynamic animations, making it useful for building realistic, physics-based interactions."`

I believe this is what they used to create the animations on `Paper`. I recall it being released right after `Paper` was published.